# Sending emails to nobody (OS X)

Tags: email, mac-osx

For some reason I want to be able to send emails to literally nobody.

I mean that if I use `mail nobody` and send something, I want the email to be immediately discarded. Completely ignored.

How can I do that?

I tried making symlink in /var/mail/nobody pointing to /dev/null, but whenever I send something there I get "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender".

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

(Forgive my poor English and noob unix skills)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an entry to `/etc/aliases`:

```
nobody: /dev/null
```

then run `newaliases`.

Comment: This answer is the correct one.  See also http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't think it's that simple ;)